# can you set a differnet session save path for different zend applications?

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, ini, zend-session

i'm creating a warehouse management system for my business which will be made up of 5 different zend applications all stored on the one webserver.

what i want to do is store 3 of the applications session data in one folder "/internal/data/session"

and the other 2 in their own folders.
i'm hoping this will prevent cross application session conflicts.

there maybe an easier way to do this i'm sure but i would like to do it this way.

in each applications config.ini i was wondering if i set there specific session.savepath directories to the ones i want will this cause a problem with the php.ini ?

basicly i'm asking for each connection to the server can i set where that connection looks for session information ?

Comment: Zend != Zend Framework!  Aaaiiieeeee!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server configuration allow it just change the session save path with your .htaccess.
In each application add :

```
php_value session.save_path '/myapplication/folder/session/'
```

Be careful and do not choose a folder which could be accessed from the web !